# Upload and edit multiple images

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Project which have multiple images.
First: I want to know how to upload multiple images.
Second: How to dynamically edit this images ( Crop , rotate , scale )

Comment: Upload multiple images at one time, or sequentially?

Comment: @ Rich Peck sequentially

Comment: Have you got Paperclip or Carrierwave installed? Or would you like to know how to use these gems?

Comment: @Rich Peck yes i can use this two gems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to set up an asset library for your application is to start by specifying a bespoke model for your assets, i.e. attachments. You can then utilise the polymorphic ActiveRecord association (http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association) to share the Attachment model across multiple models. I would also recommend using [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) as your choice of file management.

Here, in this example, I have set up a polymorphic association called 'attachable':

**attachment.rb**

```
def Attachment << ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :attachable_id, :attachable_type, :description, :file
   belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
   mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

I have also assigned two new attributes to the attachment model which will contain the associated model ID (in your case the project ID) and the attached type. Also, notice I have assigned the mount_uploader from Carrierwave to the attachment table (see carrierwave documentation for more information on this).

**project.rb**

```
def Project << ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :title, :description, :attachments_attributes
   has_many :attachments, as: :attachable, :dependent => :delete_all
   accepts_nested_attributes :attachments
end
```

Now, within my Project model, I have created a has_many relation called attachments, which references the attachable polymorphic association in the Attachment table. Furthermore, the associated attachments are dependent on the project and will be removed if the project is removed.

I have also set up the Attachment model to be editable within the Project model. Therefore you can assign nested fields within the Project forms.

Our final step is to configure the Carrierwave uploader file. I'm using [MiniMagick](https://github.com/probablycorey/mini_magick) Gem to compress and resize the images into different versions, while utilising the 'from_version' method in order to improve processing speed. See below:

**app/uploaders/file_uploader.rb**

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::Compatibility::Paperclip
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  process resize_to_fit: [500,500]

  version :large do
    process resize_to_fill: [400,400]
  end

  version :medium, :from_version => :large do 
    process resize_to_fill: [150,150]
  end

  version :small, :from_version => :medium do
    process resize_to_fill: [50,50]
  end

end
```

This should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

To upload images/videos (assets), you [PaperClip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) ir [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave). I would recommend this [simple tutorial](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images) for the basics of cropping. Ofcourse, you can customize on top of it.